# the product of a matrix and a permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, matrix-product

Can a permutation matrix (P) be used to change the rank of another matrix (M)?
Is there any literature to this effect, or to the contrary?

I've tried a few small examples and the resulting matrix (M2) seems to always have the same rank as the input matrix (M)

M2 = M P

Comment: This could be moved to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information on what is meant by this. Your question might be suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably doesn't belong on the TCS stack exchange, but I'll answer anyways.

No, multiplication by a permutation matrix will never change the rank of the matrix.  Permutation matrices are orthogonal, so if matrix M has an [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition):
$$ M = U \Sigma V^* $$
Then the product $MP$ has an SVD:
$$ MP = U \Sigma V^* P = U \Sigma W^* $$
Recall that the rank is the number of non-zero singular values.  Because $M$ and $MP$ have the same singular values $\Sigma$, they must have the same rank (and a whole bunch of other stuff).

Comment: ok - thanks for the answer and for pointing me to a better place!

Comment: SVD is an overkill here (the existence of the decomposition is nontrivial to prove). All you need to note is that $MP$ is just $M$ with its columns permuted, which obviously doesn't change the number of linearly independent columns.